# How do I read a custom section in app.config from codebehind?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, app-config

I have an `app.config` file that stores values in a few different sections. I have these snippets:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="someDataAccessLayer">
        <section name="databaseConnectionStrings" type="sometype" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <someDataAccessLayer>
     <databaseConnectionStrings>
        <databaseConnectionString name="someSQL"           
             value="database=somedatabase;Integrated Security=False;User Id=sa;server=someserver;Password=somepassword/>
     </databaseConnectionStrings>
  </someDataAccessLayer>
```

How do I read the connection string in the codebehind? Specifically the `value` which is

```
database=somedatabase;Integrated Security=False;User Id=sa;server=someserver;Password=somepassword
```

Thanks for your help! Please let me know if the question is still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration section will be associated with some .NET class to handle it:

```
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="someDataAccessLayer">
       <section name="databaseConnectionStrings" type="sometype" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
```

So to read the settings from the `<localeSettings>` section, you need to use the `ConfigurationManager` (add a reference to `System.Configuration` to your project) to get those settings into an instance of that class:

```
sometype cs = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("someDataAccessLayer/databaseConnectionStrings") as     sometype;
```

Now you have an object of type `sometype` that contains all the settings in that config section. One of those properties will be a list of database connection strings, which you can now enumerate and find the appropriate one and read it's `.Value` property.

Answer (score 0):

App.Config Settings:

```
<configuration>
        <configSections>
        </configSections>
        <connectionStrings>
            <add name="MyApp.LocalConnectionString"
                connectionString="Data Source= .\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security = true"
                providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Access at DataLayer using the `ConfigurationManager` as:

```
// add reference 
using  System.Configuration;
// then access connection string in your class
 private static string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyApp.LocalConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```